# Matlab generate multiple random matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have to generate 20 random matrices, of increasing sizes

```
200:50:1150 //sizes of 20 random matrices
```

I want to store them in like an array of matrices:

like

```
array(1) // should give me the 1st matrix of size 200x200
array(2) // should give me the 2nd matrix of size 250x250 and so on
```

I am not sure how to do this:

```
n = 200:50:1150
for i=1:20
  M(:,:,i) = rand(n(i));   //This does not work
end
```

How do I do this, is there a faster way without loops?

Comment: The code example is not working. Please either fix it or describe what output you expect.

Comment: Here you go I edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not stack your matrices of different sizes into a 3d matrix, a matrix has fixed dimensions. Use a cell array instead:

```
n = 200:50:1150;
M=cell(1,numel(n));
for ix=1:numel(n);
  M{ix} = rand(n(ix)); 
end
```

Not using a for loop won't increase the performance. Simply generating the same amount of random numbers in a single call takes the same time: `rand(sum(n.^2),1);`